# Java Double setScale and RoundingMode equivalent in C#?

Tags: java, c#, double

```
  Double toBeTruncated = new Double("3.5789055");

    Double truncatedDouble = BigDecimal.valueOf(toBeTruncated)
        .setScale(3, RoundingMode.HALF_UP)
        .doubleValue();
    return String.valueOf(truncatedDouble);
```

What is the c# equivalent syntax for the code above?(I am trying reproduce the same logic in c#)

Comment: What's your expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After analyzing for `setScale` reference here: [BigDecimal.setScale(int, java.math.RoundingMode)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#setScale(int,%20java.math.RoundingMode)) including Java's behavior to handle primitive types, this code may become most possible equivalent:

```
double? toBeTruncated = 3.5789055;

double? truncatedDouble = Math.Round(toBeTruncated.Value, 3, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
```

Points to consider with:

1) C# has nullable type instead of primitive wrapper classes, which can directly use value type definition without creating new class instance.

2) Actually, Java has converting reference type `BigDecimal` to primitive type `double` by using `doubleValue()` method, which is unused in C# context.

3) The method `setScale(3, RoundingMode.HALF_UP)` have C# equivalent as `Math.Round`, which contains additional 2 parameters to set decimal places and rounding method. `MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero` rounding model rounds up toward the next nearest number based on decimal precision.

The result of the rounding in both languages should become `3.579`.

References:

Math.Round (MSDN) = https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f5898377(v=vs.110).aspx

MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero (MSDN) = https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.midpointrounding(v=vs.110).aspx

BigDecimal.doubleValue (Oracle) = https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#doubleValue()

Comment: how can i get a represent of  String return String.valueOf(truncatedDouble);

Comment: C# doesn't have `valueOf` method, use `truncatedDouble.ToString()` or `String.Format("yourformat", truncatedDouble)` instead.